# Java permutations

Tags: java, permutation, poker

I am trying to write a program which can keep track of the number of chips each player has in poker. This is not a poker game, only a program which can keep the number of chips each player has. However, I want to be able to "bet" "call" "fold" etc and be able to automatically keep track.

My question is, is there a way for adjusting the number of players without writing each permutations? Currently, it can only keep track of 2 people. How would I make it so it can theoretically keep track of an infinite amount of people? I've written every permutation possible and I know it's not very efficient so is there a more efficient way of coding this?

I am a java noob so any help would be appreciated.

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import static java.lang.System.out;

class Chips {
static String move; //first move
static int betVal1, betVal2;
static int pot;
static int P1, P2;
static int roundcount;
static String player;
static Scanner myScanner = new Scanner(System.in);
static int turncount;
static String outcome;

public static void firstP1() { //first move when P1 start
    out.print("P1 - will you 'Bet', 'Check' or 'Fold'? ");
    move = myScanner.next();

    while (!move.equals("Bet") && !move.equals("Check") && !move.equals("Fold")){
    out.print("Please type 'Bet', 'Check' or 'Fold'");
    move = myScanner.next();
    }

    switch(move) {
    case "Bet":
        out.print("How much will you bet? If you've changed your mind: Type '0' to check and '-1' to fold. ");
        betVal1 = myScanner.nextInt();

        while (betVal1 > P1) {
            out.print("You cannot bet more than your chip count. How much will you bet? ");
            betVal1 = myScanner.nextInt();
        }
        if (betVal1 == 0) { //check
            P2aftercheck();
        }
        if (betVal1 == -1) { //fold
            P2 += pot;
            pot = 0;
            roundcount = 0;
            turncount++;

            out.print("P1: ");
            out.println(P1);
            out.print("P2: ");
            out.println(P2);
            out.println("Next turn");

            if (turncount  % 2 == 0) { //check to see who begins next turn
                player = "One";
            } else {
                player = "Two";         
            }

            if( player.equals("One")) {
                firstP1();
            } else {
                firstP2();
            }

        }


        pot += betVal1;
        P1 -= betVal1;
        //out.println(betVal);
        //out.print(pot);
        P2afterbet();
        break;

    case "Check":
        P2aftercheck();
        break;

    case "Fold":
        P2 += pot;
        pot = 0;
        roundcount = 0;
        turncount++;

        if (turncount  % 2 == 0) {
            player = "One";
        } else {
            player = "Two";         
        }

        if( player.equals("One")) {
            firstP1();
        } else {
            firstP2();
        }
        break;

    }
}

public static void firstP2() { //first move when P2 start
    out.print("P2 - will you 'Bet', 'Check' or 'Fold'? ");
    move = myScanner.next();

    while (!move.equals("Bet") && !move.equals("Check") && !move.equals("Fold")){
    out.print("Please type 'Bet', 'Check' or 'Fold' ");
    move = myScanner.next();
    }

    switch(move) {
    case "Bet":
        out.print("How much will you bet? ");
        betVal2 = myScanner.nextInt();
        while (betVal2 > P2) {
            out.print("You can not bet more than your chip count. How much will you bet? ");
            betVal2 = myScanner.nextInt();
        }
        pot += betVal2;
        P2 -= betVal2;
        //out.println(betVal);
        //out.print(pot);
        P1afterbet();
        break;

    case "Check":
        P1aftercheck();
        break;

    case "Fold":
        P1 += pot;
        pot = 0;
        roundcount = 0;
        turncount++;

        out.print("P1: ");
        out.println(P1);
        out.print("P2: ");
        out.println(P2);
        out.println("Next turn");

        if (turncount  % 2 == 0) {
            player = "One";
        } else {
            player = "Two";         
        }

        if( player.equals("One")) {
            firstP1();
        } else {
            firstP2();
        }
        break;

    }
}

public static void P1afterbet() { //P1 move after P2 bet
    out.print("P1 - will you 'Bet', 'Call' or 'Fold'? ");
    move = myScanner.next();

    while (!move.equals("Bet") && !move.equals("Call") && !move.equals("Fold")){
        out.print("Please type 'Bet', 'Check' or 'Fold' ");
        move = myScanner.next();
    }

    switch(move) {
    case "Bet":
        out.print("How much will you bet? ");
        betVal1 = myScanner.nextInt();
        while (betVal1 < betVal2){
            out.print("Please bet at least ");
            out.print(betVal2);
            out.println(" chips.");
            out.print("How much will you bet? ");
            betVal1 = myScanner.nextInt();
        }

        pot += betVal1;
        P1 -= betVal1;
        P2afterbet();
        break;

    case "Call":
        pot += betVal1;
        P1 -= betVal1;
        roundcount++;
        if (roundcount == 4){
            roundend();
        }
        if( player.equals("P1")) {
            firstP1();
        } else {
            firstP2();
        }
        break;

    case "Fold":
        P2 += pot;
        pot = 0;
        roundcount = 0;
        turncount++;

        out.print("P1: ");
        out.println(P1);
        out.print("P2: ");
        out.println(P2);
        out.println("Next turn");

        if (turncount  % 2 == 0) {
            player = "One";
        } else {
            player = "Two";         
        }

        if( player.equals("One")) {
            firstP1();
        } else {
            firstP2();
        }
        break;
    }
}

public static void P1aftercheck() { //P1 move after P2 check
    out.print("P1 - will you 'Bet', 'Check' or 'Fold'? ");
    move = myScanner.next();

    while (!move.equals("Bet") && !move.equals("Check") && !move.equals("Fold")){
    out.print("Please type 'Bet', 'Check' or 'Fold'");
    move = myScanner.next();
    }

    switch(move) {
    case "Bet":
        out.print("How much will you bet? ");
        betVal1 = myScanner.nextInt();
        while (betVal1 > P1) {
            out.print("You can not bet more than your chip count. How much will you bet? ");
            betVal1 = myScanner.nextInt();
        }
        pot += betVal1;
        P1 -= betVal1;
        //out.println(betVal);
        //out.print(pot);
        P2afterbet();
        break;

    case "Check":
        roundcount++;
        if (roundcount == 4) {
            roundend();
        }
        if( player.equals("One")) {
            firstP1();
        } else {
            firstP2();
        }
        break;

    case "Fold":
        P2 += pot;
        pot = 0;
        roundcount=0;
        turncount++; 

        out.print("P1: ");
        out.println(P1);
        out.print("P2: ");
        out.println(P2);
        out.println("Next turn");

        if (turncount  % 2 == 0) {
            player = "One";
        } else {
            player = "Two";         
        }

        if( player.equals("One")) {
            firstP1();
        } else {
            firstP2();
        }
        break;

    }
}

public static void P2afterbet() { //P2 move after P1 bet
    out.print("P2 - will you 'Bet', 'Call' or 'Fold'? ");
    move = myScanner.next();

    while (!move.equals("Bet") && !move.equals("Call") && !move.equals("Fold")){
    out.print("Please type 'Bet', 'Check' or 'Fold'");
    move = myScanner.next();
    }

    switch(move) {
    case "Bet":
        out.print("How much will you bet? ");
        betVal2 = myScanner.nextInt();
        while (betVal2 > P2) {
            out.print("You can not bet more than your chip count. How much will you bet? ");
            betVal2 = myScanner.nextInt();
        }
        while (betVal2 < betVal1) {
            out.print("You must bet at least ");
            out.print(betVal1);
            betVal2 = myScanner.nextInt();
        }
        pot += betVal2;
        P2 -= betVal2;
        //out.println(betVal);
        //out.print(pot);
        P1afterbet();
        break;

    case "Call":
        P2 -= betVal1;
        pot += betVal1;
        roundcount++;
        if (roundcount == 4){
            roundend();
        }
        if( player.equals("P1")) {
            firstP1();
        } else {
            firstP2();
        }
        break;

    case "Fold":
        P1 += pot;
        pot = 0;
        roundcount = 0;
        turncount++;

        out.print("P1: ");
        out.println(P1);
        out.print("P2: ");
        out.println(P2);
        out.println("Next turn");

        if (turncount  % 2 == 0) {
            player = "One";
        } else {
            player = "Two";         
        }

        if( player.equals("One")) {
            firstP1();
        } else {
            firstP2();
        }
        break;

    }
}

public static void P2aftercheck() { //P2 move after P1 check
    out.print("P2 - will you 'Bet', 'Check' or 'Fold'? ");
    move = myScanner.next();

    while (!move.equals("Bet") && !move.equals("Check") && !move.equals("Fold")){
    out.print("Please type 'Bet', 'Check' or 'Fold'");
    move = myScanner.next();
    }

    switch(move) {
    case "Bet":
        out.print("How much will you bet? ");
        betVal2 = myScanner.nextInt();
        while (betVal2 > P1) {
            out.print("You can not bet more than your chip count. How much will you bet? ");
            betVal2 = myScanner.nextInt();
        }
        pot += betVal2;
        P2 -= betVal2;
        //out.println(betVal);
        //out.print(pot);
        P1afterbet();
        break;

    case "Check":
        roundcount++;
        if (roundcount == 4){
            roundend();
        }
        if( player.equals("One")) {
            firstP1();
        } else {
            firstP2();
        }

        break;

    case "Fold":
        P1 += pot;
        pot = 0;
        roundcount=0;
        turncount++;

        out.print("P1: ");
        out.println(P1);
        out.print("P2: ");
        out.println(P2);
        out.println("Next turn");

        if (turncount  % 2 == 0) {
            player = "One";
        } else {
            player = "Two";         
        }

        if( player.equals("One")) {
            firstP1();
        } else {
            firstP2();
        }

        break;

    }
}

public static void roundend() {
    out.print("Who won the round? 'P1' or 'P2'? ");
    outcome = myScanner.next();
    turncount++;

    if (turncount  % 2 == 0) {
        player = "One";
    } else {
        player = "Two";         
    }

    while (!outcome.equals("P1") && !outcome.equals("P2")){
        out.print("Please type 'P1' or 'P2'");
        outcome = myScanner.next();
    }

    if (outcome.equals("P1")){
        P1 += pot;
        pot = 0;
        roundcount = 0;

        out.print("P1: ");
        out.println(P1);
        out.print("P2: ");
        out.println(P2);
        out.println("Next turn");

        if (P1 != 0 && P2 != 0){
            if( player.equals("One")) {
                firstP1();
            } else {
                firstP2();
            }
        } else if (P1 == 0) {
            out.print("P1 is out of chips. P2 Wins!");
        } else {
            out.print("P2 is out of chips. P2 Wins!");
        }
    } else {
        P2 += pot;
        pot = 0;
        roundcount = 0;

        out.print("P1: ");
        out.println(P1);
        out.print("P2: ");
        out.println(P2);
        out.println("Next turn");

        if (P1 != 0 && P2 != 0) {
            if( player.equals("P1")) {
                firstP1();
            } else {
                firstP2();
            }
        } else if (P1 == 0) {
            out.print("P1 is out of chips. P2 Wins!");
        } else {
            out.print("P2 is out of chips. P2 Wins!");
        }
    } 

    System.exit(0);
}

public static void main(String args[]){

    pot = 0;
    roundcount = 0; //status within turn i.e. Flop, Turn, River
    turncount = 2; //use for who starts

    out.print("Please enter starting chip count ");
    P1 = myScanner.nextInt();
    P2 = P1;

    firstP1();
}
```

}

Comment: too long code. concrete your question please.

Comment: @logoff At least it's an almost correct SSCCE (you could argue about the first *S*).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes but you will need to re-think the way your program is designed.

The easiest way to do this would be to create a `Player` class, and implement every action a player performs as a method within this class. In order to manage the Player's chips you would have a variable `Player.chips` that is either globally accessible or managed with methods such as `Player.getChips()` and `Player.setChips()`.

For multiple players you would have an array of `Player`'s ie.

```
Player[] Players; 
Players[0] = new Player();
Players[1] = new Player();
```

The following post may help you more (similar problem but using Blackjack instead of Poker ) - [How to initialize an array of objects in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5889034/how-to-initialize-an-array-of-objects-in-java).

Answer (score 0):

I think the main thing you're missing is that **methods can take parameters**.

So rather than having things in the style of;

```
private static void player1Move() {
    //player 1 takes his move
}

private static void player2Move() {
    //player 2 takes her move
}
```

You would have;

```
private static void move(int playerID) {
    //player playerID takes their move
}
```

Java naming conventions dictate that method and field names must start with a lower-case letter, class names with an upper case. Also don't forget that **methods can return stuff, useful stuff**. All your methods are `void`, try thinking about how they could return some kind of status to the calling function.

For example you could have a method `int getBet(int playerID)` which requests the user to type their bet amount, checks it against their chip stack (using the playerID parameter), and returns their bet amount when it is valid. Much better than rewriting everything over and over right?

Final tip: if you find yourself copying a **single** line of code, you're doing something wrong.

Edit: Nathan Dunn's answer is also very relevant. Java is an object oriented language, learn to leverage that fact. You certainly need a `Player` class.