# What is this java.lang.NullPointerException?

Tags: java, nullpointerexception

I coded a short script to learn about Java array:

```
class Dog {
  String name;
  void bark() {
    System.out.println(name + " is barking");
  }

  void eat() {
    System.out.println(name + " is eating");
  }
}

class mypets {
    public static void main(String [] args) {

    Dog dogA = new Dog();

    dogA.name="Lassy";
    dogA.bark();
    dogA.eat();

    Dog[] myDogs = new Dog[3];
    myDogs[0].name = "Barney";
    myDogs[0].bark();
  }
}
```

I then compiled and run my program:

```
C:\Java>javac mypets.java

C:\Java>java mypets
Lassy is barking
Lassy is eating
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
        at mypets.main(mypets.java:22)
```

What did I do wrong? I tried googling for that dreaded "java.lang.NullPointerException" but honestly I am confused right now.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

An array is like a row of boxes that can hold objects; when you create an array, though, those boxes are empty. The `NullPointerException` is Java's way of telling you this. So, when you say

```
Dog[] myDogs = new Dog[3];
myDogs[0].name = "Barney";
```

You're trying to set the name of the `Dog` in the first box, but there *is* no such `Dog` -- the box is empty. You need to put a `Dog` in the box to make this work:

```
Dog[] myDogs = new Dog[3];
myDogs[0] = new Dog();
myDogs[0].name = "Barney";
```

Then it will work.

Answer (score 2):

When you initialize an array, each element of the array is assigned a default value. In the case of an object, the default value is null. Invoking methods on a `null` reference results in a `NullPointerException`. You must instantiate each `Dog` using `new`

```
Dog[] myDogs = new Dog[3];
```

Each element of myDogs is assigned null.

```
for(int i = 0; i < myDogs.length; i ++) {
    myDogs[i] = new Dog();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

`NullPointException` basically means you are attempting to reference an object or objects that haven't been initialized yet...

In your code, you are doing...

```
Dog[] myDogs = new Dog[3];
```

This will create an array that can contain 3 elements of `Dog`, it does not create any instances of `Dog`, so when you do this...

```
myDogs[0].name = "Barney";
myDogs[0].bark();
```

`myDogs[0]` is actually `null`.

Instead, you need to first allocate a new `Dog` to the element BEFORE you try to access it.

```
myDogs[0] = new Dog();
myDogs[0].name = "Barney";
myDogs[0].bark();
```

You might like to take a read through [Arrays](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/arrays.html) of more details

Comment: Thank you so mucj=h for the link.

Answer (score 1):

You need to initialise each reference in the Array. Following is the edited code.
See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5364278/creating-an-array-of-objects-in-java) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5889034/how-to-initialize-an-array-of-objects-in-java) for more info.

```
 class Dog {
      String name;
      void bark() {
        System.out.println(name + " is barking");
      }

      void eat() {
        System.out.println(name + " is eating");
      }
    }

    class mypets {
        public static void main(String [] args) {

        Dog dogA = new Dog();

        dogA.name="Lassy";
        dogA.bark();
        dogA.eat();

        Dog[] myDogs = new Dog[3];

        //Lines Added
        for(int i=0; i<3; i++)
            myDogs[i] = new Dog();
        //End   

        myDogs[0].name = "Barney";
        myDogs[0].bark();
      }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to create objects and put in the array before you can use it.

Like

```
Dog[] myDogs = new Dog[3];
myDogs[0] = new Dog();
myDogs[0].name = "Barney";
myDogs[0].bark();
```

Comment: Thanks mate. Appreciate that

Comment: @RamlangPorigi NullPointerException is going to be with you as long as you are in Java. So understand the concept well. :D

Answer (score 0):

`NullPointerException` says that it is an exception that you (your reference variable) are pointing to null (object), and yet you intend to do some operation on that (which should be wrong).

In simplest terms, if you declare a variable and do not assign an object it points to null

```
MyClass myRef;//equivalent to MyClass myRef = null;
```

and then try to do some operation on it

```
myRef.doSomething(); //it's a null pointer exception
```

then you get `NullPointerException`