# How to initialize an array of objects?

Tags: java, arrays, array-initialization

I just looked at this [SO Post:](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5889034/how-to-initialize-an-array-of-objects-in-java)

However, the [Columbia professor's notes](http://www.cs.nyu.edu/~cconway/teaching/cs1007/notes/arrays.pdf) does it the way below.  See page 9.

```
Foo foos = new Foo[12] ;
```

Which way is correct?  They seem to say different things.

Particularly, in the notes version there isn't `[]`.

Comment: This won't compile in Java.

Comment: I suspect it was merely a typo on the part of the prof.  Don't turn it into a federal case (or worse yet, a Congressional catfight).

Comment: (And it should be noted that the term "initialize" must be carefully interpreted.  The `new` operation allocates and initializes an array of *references* to Foo, but it does not create any Foo objects -- the array is initially all `null` references.)

Comment: I glanced briefly at the notes.  Aside from the typos they appear to be reasonable and a logical progression.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This simply won't compile in Java (because you're assigning a value of an array type to a variable of a the non-array type `Foo`):

```
Foo foos = new Foo[12];
```

it's rejected by `javac` with the following error (See also: http://ideone.com/0jh9YE):

```
test.java:5: error: incompatible types
        Foo foos = new Foo[12];
```

To have it compile, declare `foo` to be of type `Foo[]` and then just loop over it:

```
Foo[] foo = new Foo[12];  # <<<<<<<<<

for (int i = 0; i < 12; i += 1) {
    foos[i] = new Foo();
}
```

Comment: @JeroenVannevel: amended my answer.

Comment: @nativist.bill.cutting: Why couldn't you create your own example and verify that it doesn't compile? You say you're not lazy, but how did you try this before asking Eric to do it for you?

Comment: @nativist.bill.cutting: so what made you unaccept my answer and accept another one that says the same thing except with no explanation?

Answer (score 1):

```
Foo[] foos = new Foo[12] ; //declaring array 

for(int i=0;i<12;i++){
   foos[i] = new Foo();  //initializing the array with foo object

}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can't do this

```
Foo foos = new Foo[12] ;
```

change to

```
Foo[] foos = new Foo[12];
```

there was a typo in the document on page 9. Also there's a typo on page 10

```
int[] grades = new int[3]
```

I would not read the whole document if the typos are on each page.

Answer (score 0):

Declare by this way.

```
Foo[] foos = new Foo[12];
```

Answer (score 0):

```
//declaring array of 12 Foo elements in Java8 style
Foo[] foos = Stream.generate(Foo::new).limit(12).toArray(Foo[]::new);

// instead of
Foo[] foos = new Foo[12];
for(int i=0;i<12;i++){
   foos[i] = new Foo();

}
```