# Java Array Set Up

Tags: java, arrays

I am working on a code for one of my projects and it requires me to write an array. How do I achieve comment 5a? And did I get comment 5 right?

```
// 4. declare an array of players

Player [] team = new Player[];

// 5. loop over teamsize

for( int index = 0; index < team.length; index++)

// 5a. instantiate the i'th team member
```

Comment: For questions like these, it's better for you to read up on some Java tutorials instead of asking on StackOverflow.

Comment: Yes and `team[index] = new Player(/* Fill with arguments */);`

Comment: However, SO is generally for code you're having problems with, not code you don't know how to use. Google is for that. :)

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to initialize an array of objects in Java](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5889034/how-to-initialize-an-array-of-objects-in-java) and [How to initialize an array of objects?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19198196/how-to-initialize-an-array-of-objects)..

Answer (score 2):

Yes you did get 5 right but I would suggest something like:

```
int length = team.length // to avoid unnecessarily calling it every iteration
for (int index = 0 ; index < length ; index++) {
   // ...
}
```

For 5a, just instantiate a `Player` class. If you don't know how to do that, read the [Java tutorials](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/objectcreation.html). They are very helpful.

Just another thing for 5a, the instruction says `i'th` team member, this just means `nth` (because `i` is the common variable name for **index** which is what you are already using)