# Java How to read an array of inputs

Tags: java, arrays, string

I have a do while loop that asks for 2 forms of input 3 times.

I thought about putting these inputs into 2 arrays to be output later, but it ain't working.

Here's my code for you to look at:

```
int i = 0;
do {
   System.out.print("Enter a name ");
   String name = scanner.nextLine();

   System.out.print("Enter age ");
   String age = input.nextLine();
   newAge = Integer.parseInt(age);
   i++;
} while (i <= 3);
```

I want to output the values as such:

Names are:    Name1; Name2; Name3

But I want to add the 3 ages together to make a totalAge variable.

Comment: You "thought" about putting the inputs into arrays, but did you actually try writing code that did that?  If so, please post the code you tried.

Comment: You say you tried arrays, but there are none in your code. Show us the code you tried that isn't working.

Comment: That's why I posted on here, I don't know how to get started.

Comment: Good place to start then: [Java Tutorials](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/arrays.html)

Answer (score -2, accepted):

```
int i = 0;
String[] name = new String[3];
int[] age = new int[3];
do {
   System.out.print("Enter a name ");
   name[i] = scanner.nextLine();

   System.out.print("Enter age ");
   age[i] = Integer.parseInteger(input.nextLine());
   ;
   i++;
} while (i <= 3);
```

Comment: pls let him try 1st

Comment: Thanks Shiro, how do I then reference these outside so that I can print each name and then add the 3 ages outside the do while loop?

Comment: For example: System.out.println("Name: " + name[0] + " Age: " + age[0])

Answer (score -2):

You can declare two arrays for `name` and `age` inputs, or you can create [a class](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/java_object_classes.htm) that holds them both, call it `Person` or something like that and [create an array of these](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5889064/5922757).

```
class Person {
    public String name;
    public Integer age;
}
```

You don't need a `do-while` loop, it will look better with a `for`, or [even better with `enhanced for`](https://blogs.oracle.com/CoreJavaTechTips/entry/using_enhanced_for_loops_with):

```
int personsAmount = 3;
Person[] persons = new Person[personsAmount];
for (Person person : persons) {
    person = new Person();

    System.out.print("Enter a name ");
    person.name = scanner.nextLine();

    System.out.print("Enter age ");
    person.age = Integer.parseInt(scanner.nextLine());
}
```

Comment: @Shank So you think a Java course or a tutorial would teach arrays before arbitrary classes? Would be funny.

Comment: Albeit I don't think that classes are confusing for newbies, this answer isn't working anyway. But it proofs that [Java uses pass-by-value](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40480/is-java-pass-by-reference-or-pass-by-value).