# Compile time initialization of an array of classes with an array of ints inside

Tags: java, arrays, initialization

```
struct S
{
    int arr[3];
    int x;
};


S s[3] = {{{1, 2, 3}, 111},
          {{2, 3, 4}, 222},
          {{3, 4, 5}, 333}};
```

The above code is C++

Is it possible to do something similar in Java? i.e. do a compile time initialization?

Comment: `String arr [] = {"Hello", "World"};`

Comment: @ScaryWombat - My example has an array int inside each class object

Comment: You would use a class instead of a `struct`.  See this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/60959439/2310289

Comment: @ScaryWombat - yeah, I know that. My question is how I would initialize the 3 elements of S::arr in each instance of S

Comment: You pass them as parameter to constructor.

Comment: @ScaryWombat  - is there no way to do it other than having an explicit constructor? In C++, I can do it without writing an explicit constructor

Comment: I don't think so. Your other way would be to access variables directly or use a method.  It might be worth checking java records.

Comment: or perhaps just use c# to do your project. I am aware this isn't the answer you are looking but I am not sure as well what you are expecting out of java.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Is it possible to do something similar in Java? i.e. do a compile time initialization?

No, not possible. Java allows compile-time constants solely for `static final` variables, with a primitive type or String type, initialized on the same line, and not with null. This can be 'recursive', and some basic math is allowed, as long as it all remains constant (see [JLS §15.28](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.28)).

Crucially then, integer arrays don't count.

But, the question one needs to ask is: **why** do you want it to be? Java isn't like C, and compile time constants don't buy you anything, except [A] if you have class file A that contains a constant, and you refer to it in B, and then compile B, and then A is not available at runtime, it won't matter. This is true, but, this rarely to never matters and is in fact somewhat annoying (if you later recompile A without recompiling B, B won't pick up teh change if it was a constant), and [B] it saves you some code that runs once per application execution.

B is also irrelevant - JVM bootup is orders of magnitude more expensive than a minimal C application's bootup; this JVM bootup completely dwarfs any concern here.

Thus, trivially, you think you want a compile time constant but you probably don't. If you really do, the answer is a simple: **impossible**.

If it's not so much about it being a compile time constant, but more about writing it in a succint manner, java has syntax sugar for 2D arrays, but does not have particularly fancy syntax to make structs and initialize them without naming them.

Note that in idiomatic java, the `[]` goes after the type and never after the variable. Yes, you can write it after the variable, but nobody does this - it's a holdover from 30 years ago when java syntax was explicitly designed to appeal to C coders.

Thus:

```
public record S(int[] arr, int x) {}

S[] s = {
  new S(new int[] {1, 2, 3}, 111),
  new S(new int[] {2, 3, 4}, 222),
  new S(new int[] {3, 4, 5}, 333)
};
```

is about as short as you can make it.
You can omit the `new S[]` part only when writing an initializing expression for a variable declaration. `S[] s` is a variable declaration so we can skip it there, but the array values we're passing in aren't, thus, the `new int[]` part is not skippable. You could get fancy with constructors and do something like:

```
public record S(int[] arr, int x) {
    public S(int x, int... arr) {
        this(arr, x);
    }
}

// then you can go with:
S[] s = {
  new S(111, 1, 2, 3),
  new S(222, 2, 3, 4),
  new S(333, 3, 4, 5)
};
```

Golfing any further than this would take you then rather dark, extremely non-idiomatic and ill-advised java syntax hackery.

Comment: Thank you - but `new S(new int[] {1, 2, 3}, 111}),` this seems to be missing an `{`

Comment: ON the contrary, the final `}` should be deleted.

Comment: Can you show how you have defined S in the 1st sample code - i am unable to get it to compile

Comment: "Java syntax was explicitly designed to appeal to C coders" ... and C was explicitly designed to appeal to B coders, and ... It's really appalling how much bad syntax has come to us via that path, and how little via the best syntax designers of the 1960s: by whom I mean Wirth and Hoare.

Comment: @user93353 The first code segment works for me, but it does require Java 16 or whenever records were introduced (I dozed off).